# Cygwin and Tmux run-shell

Tags: bash, tmux, cygwin

I've run into a somewhat odd issue on `Cygwin` when I'm using the Tmux command `run-shell`.

Given the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -d '' var << EOF
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
EOF

echo "Running in shell: $SHELL"


while read line;
do
    echo $line
done <<EOF
$var
EOF


while read line;
do
    echo $line
done < <(echo "$var")
```

Running it directly with bash works just fine (`bash ~/test_script.sh`), producing:

```
Running in shell: /bin/bash
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
```

When I try to run this using `tmux run-shell test_script.sh` I get:

```
Running in shell: /usr/bin/bash
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
Line 3.
'/cygdrive/c/Users/gusta/test_script.sh' returned 2
```

Now, I'm aware that the second loop is a Bashism, so I've probably missed some kind of configuration to ensure that Tmux properly uses Bash. Anyone know what I'm missing here? So far I've tried setting:

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash
set-option -g default-command /bin/bash
```

in `.tmux.conf` but as far as I've been able to tell, that isn't working.

(This has been tested on `tmux 2.2` and `tmux master`.)

Comment: Is there a copying error in your `#/usr/bin/env bash` line? It should be `#!`

Comment: Ah, yes that's a typo on my part. Error is still there however. Good catch though!